# Bootstrap dropdown doesn't work

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jsp

Hello I'm trying to do a website with Java EE on a glassfish server and Intellij IDE. I'm trying to have a bootstrap navbar with dropdown menu but the dropdown doesn't work. 
There's my architecture :[image]

And there is my code : 
1) layout.tag

```
<%@tag description="Overall Page template" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@attribute name="title" fragment="true"%>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value="/lib/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value="/lib/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value="/css/custom.css"/>"/>
    <title>MyChild - <jsp:invoke fragment="title"/></title>
</head>

<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
            </form>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>


<div id="body">
    <jsp:doBody/>
</div>


<div id="pagefooter">
    <p>FOOTER</p>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript" href="<c:url value="/lib/jquery/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"/>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" href="<c:url value="/lib/jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/jquery-ui.min.js"/>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" href="<c:url value="/lib/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"/>"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

2) index.jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib prefix="t" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" %>
<t:layout>
  <jsp:attribute name="title">home</jsp:attribute>
  <jsp:body>
    <p>WELCOME</p>
  </jsp:body>
</t:layout>
```

The bootstrap CSS work but the dropdown menu doesn't work. And if I click to 'source code' in firefox I can see all of the needed files (bootstrap.min.js etc) so the system know where the files are.

I saw that we must have a valid doctype and I can see when I click "source code" on firefox that I have 5 empty lines before  tag. Maybe the problem is there ?

ps: It works with CDN.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [this jsp](https://github.com/ajkr195/springbootrocks/blob/master/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/fragments/header.jsp) and notice the sequence. I am using all bootstrap/jquery/popper css and js as you mentioned. And its working correctly (as expected).

Answer (score -1):

Try adding the below code after the scripts tag at the end

```js
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Doesn't work... <script>alert("hello World");</script> works but jquery code doesn't work.

Comment: Can you place your jQuery link first of all js and css links and try ? For testing purpose try to use the cdn links for all the scripts and see if it works.

Comment: That Works with bootstrap CDN ! Can it be possible that bootstrap js cannot access to the others bootstrap dependencies ?

Comment: Did you try putting jQuery on top of all the scripts and links ? Did that work ?

Comment: And I think the problem may be arising due to the compatibility between jQuery and jQuery-ui

Comment: I have the last version of bootstrap, jquery and jquery UI and this worked in an other project. Putting jquery on top doesn't work...